# Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/app/magento-vars.php

Tags: magento2

I am trying to configure Magento 2 CE on a localhost using Docker.  I am getting these errors when I visit localhost:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/app/magento-vars.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

Have googled for this and not seeing any recommendations,

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem,just create app directory in the root folder of your magento container and place the magento-vars.php file there.

Clear the cache and run.

Hope it works!